# I would like to run a vtk example in c++ and I don't know how to import the data that is needed

Tags: c++, vtk

I would like to implement this example in vtk:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/BoxClipStructuredPoints

and I need to import the data :

HeadMRVolume.mhd and HeadMRVolume.raw.gz

Where do I need to save this data ? I copy pasted this data to the build folder but also to the root folder but it failed to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compiled the very same example you shared, you just need to put the data files next to the compiled binary you made, and pass the metadata file path as an argument to this executable.

Just open a terminal in the folder where the binary and the datafiles are and type :

```
./BoxClipStructuredPoints HeadMRVolume.mhd (for Unix-based systems)
BoxClipStructuredPoints.exe HeadMRVolume.mhd (for Windows)
```

NB : " WINDOWS USERS PLEASE NOTE: Be sure to add the VTK bin directory to your path. This will resolve the VTK dll's at run time. "

Comment: do I have first to change the cxx file ? because if you see it invokes the file with a different name..

Comment: No and no. You do not need to change the name (but you can) because the used file is passed as a parameter. It's not hardcoded in the ".cxx" file.